# Turn on GPS when App starts in QT

Tags: qt, gps

So I was working on a positioning app which needs GPS to be turned on. So I wanted a way to automatically turn on GPS in the background, if even possible with high accuracy or atleast have a popup window come up so the user can turn on the GPS right away. But sadly I couldn't find a single way to do so in QT, if there is a solution it's always written in Java. Can I somehow do it in QT too or import Java code in it?

Would I also be able to keep my GPS updates running in the background? Because as soon as I press the home button the updates stop to come up in the console with qDebug... or is it just the qDebug function that can't run when the app is not open?

Answer (score 0):

> Will I be able to use GPS in my Qt app?

First, check if the target platform has GPS and/or capable of resolving geo-coordinates. Next check the manual out: [Qt Location](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtlocation-index.html). Mind that they refer to this functionality as 'location' so it maybe partially available even without actual GPS unit on device if there is another provider type (I guess partially and not for all platforms). I could only find this [list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_(software)) of platforms supported:

> Qt Location   Classes for accessing GPS and other location services and
>   for mapping and navigation. Split off from the Qt 4 Mobility module of
>   Qt Location. Supported on Android, BlackBerry, iOS, Linux (using
>   GeoClue), Windows and Sailfish OS.

As for starting the GPS (location services provider) there is such entry for QML for sure called [start()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtpositioning-positionsource.html#start-method) of `PositionSource`. It also implies one can find the same functionality in C++ as well.

> Would I also be able to keep my GPS updates running in the background? Because as soon as I press the home button the updates stop to come up in the console with qDebug... or is it just the qDebug function that can't run when the app is not open?

Home button: it implies Android? Unclear what you ask but the Android app lifecycle is a bit different matter than that. The GPS will be working independently of your app but will the app respond to messages is more determined by Android.